# Have I been doing locks wrong this whole time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I was reading [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) about thread safety in Singletons, and it got me thinking that I don't understand the `lock` method.

In the second version, the author has this:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas I would've done something more like this:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (instance)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why would you use a `padlock` object, rather than locking the actual object you want to lock?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What would you expect to happen the first time you accessed the `Instance` property, before you've got an object to lock on?

(Hint: `lock(null)` goes bang...)

As a separate measure, I almost always avoid locking on "the actual object" - because typically there may well be other code which that reference is exposed to, and I don't necessarily know what that's going to lock on. Even if your version *did* work, what would happen if some external code wrote:

```
// Make sure only one thread is ever in this code...
lock (Singleton.Instance)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now no-one else can even *get* the instance while that code is executing, because they'll end up blocked in the getter. The lock in the getter isn't meant to be guarding against that - it's only meant to be guarding against multiple access *within the getter*.

The more tightly you can keep control of your locks, the easier it is to reason about them and to avoid deadlocks.

I *very occasionally* take a lock on a "normal" object if:

- I'm not exposing that reference outside that class
- I have confidence that the type itself (which will always have a reference to `this`, of course) won't lock on itself.

(All of this is a reason to avoid locking on `this`, too, of course...)

Fundamentally, I believe the idea of allowing you to lock on any object was a bad idea in Java, and it was a bad move to copy it in .NET :(

Comment: You can't lock an object that does not exist.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  Thanks!  Now, if I knew that `instance` wasn't null for whatever reason, would my method be fine?

Comment: Oh... here comes the author :)

Comment: @MattGrande: See my edit for why it still wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @Matt: well, not really. The `instance` is available outside, so you cannot be sure that no one has locked it before. With a private `padlock` you *can* be sure of that.

Comment: @MattGrande IF `instance` were always non-null - what is the purpose the `lock` ???

Comment: So, after reading all this, I'm wonder why you even need to pass an object to the lock.  It'd make more sense if it was `lock { /* whatever */ }`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MattGrande: There still needs to be *something* for the lock to hang on. Otherwise what's the scope? In an instance method, you may want it to have the scope of the object, or maybe the class... and you may want multiple blocks guarded by the same lock.

Comment: @MattGrande Without an object to lock on, you couldn't prevent two different blocks of code that work on the same data from racing each other.

Comment: Of course, duh.  I don't think my brain is firing on all cylinders today!

Comment: @MattGrande: I think what you are getting at in a roundabout way is that you want to lock **the variable**, because of course that is what you are mutating. That makes perfect sense; if you want to keep people out of your bathroom you put a lock *on the bathroom*; you don't put a lock somewhere else in the house and require people to lock that object before they enter the bathroom. Though that conceptually makes sense, in .NET you unfortunately cannot lock *variables*, you can only lock *objects*.

Answer (score 2):

Locking on `this` or any other non-private object is dangerous because it can lead to deadlocks if someone else also tries to use that object for synchronization.

It's not terribly likely, which is why people can be in the habit of doing it for years without ever getting bitten.  But it is still possible, and the cost of a private instance of `object` probably isn't great enough to justify running the risk.

Answer (score 1):

For locking you can use any kind of object, the type really doesn't matter, it just used as a flag and only one thread can hold it in a time.

It is of course possible to have this as locking param. But I guess the main reason why it's not recommended is that other class somewhere can also use instance of your class as locking object and that can cause strage problems